# RTRIM(CLOB field) in Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, clob

Please suppose I have a CLOB field in an Oracle table, in which I have stored the creation script of a package/procedure/function.

I would like to remove all blanks **at the end of every line**, but:

a) DBMS_LOB.TRIM (CLOB field) is a procedure and not a function;
b) RTRIM (CLOB) don't fail, but does not work to achieve this.

How can I solve my problem?

Please note that the spaces at the beginning of every line are useful for indentation of the PL/SQL source code stored in the CLOB field, so they haven't to be removed.

Thank you in advance for your kind help and cooperation.

Comment: Have you considered opening the file , Iterate each row , trim the trailing spaces and write the CLOB back to the table ?

Comment: I would prefer a REGEXP_REPLACE approach.  The sequence <SPACE> (how many times you want) followed by CHR(10) has to be replaced as CHR(10) simply.  How can I achieve this?

Comment: select REGEXP_REPLACE (MY_CLOB_FIELD, '\s*'||chr(10), chr(10)) from MY_TABLE;    is totally INEFFICIENT :(

Comment: are you trying to update the table, or simply remove spaces on select?  How big is this table?

Comment: This table is a backup table for PL/SQL packages, procedures and functions, so it grows every day.  Every row contains two CLOBs: the CLOB of the package/procedure/function before review, and the CLOB of the package/procedure/function after review.  Every CLOB can reach up to 50K rows of about 80 characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove spaces at the end of each line you could use `regexp_replace()`  regular expression function:

```
regexp_replace(col, '\s+('||CHR(10)||'|$)', chr(10))
```

Here is an example(Note: `replace` function is used just to highlight spaces):

```
with t1(col) as(
  select to_clob('begin  '||chr(10)||chr(32)||chr(32)||'something is going on here'||chr(32)||chr(32)||chr(10)|| 'end'||chr(32)||chr(32))
    from dual
)
select replace(col, ' ', '_') as with_spaces
     , replace(
               regexp_replace(col, '\s+('||CHR(10)||'|$)', chr(10))
               , ' '
               , '_'
               ) as without_spaces
  from t1
```

Result:

```
WITH_SPACES                           WITHOUT_SPACES
---------------------------------------------------------------------
begin__                               begin
__something_is_going_on_here__        __something_is_going_on_here
end__                                 end
```

Comment: The PL/SQL scripts stored in the CLOB field are very long (about 50K rows), so this solutions - which works properly! - is inefficient, this means it takes a long time.  Do you think that could exist a solution more efficient?

Answer (score 0):

If the last line has any trailing spaces then Nick's solution adds an extra line.
It should have been
`regexp_replace(col, '\s+('||CHR(10)||'|$)', '\1')`

Even so that strips any blank lines out.
Better this solution, but it only deals with trailing spaces and tabs
`regexp_replace(col, '[ ' ||chr(9)|| ']+$', '', 1, 0, 'm')`